# Trying to get Faeye icon inside the input box

Tags: css, reactjs

a few days ago I used MUI Components and it was very easy and straight forward to setup an input field that contained the eye icon which when clicked would switch toan eye icon with a slash through it and then hide your password. Unfortunately the team said no to MUI or even Tailwind.  My question is how can I recreate the same thing with just react styled components. I am having a hard time even getting the eye in the input field.I dont need help with the state or functionality but how do I get the eye in the dang field. Please see my code below so far:

```js
<div className="form-input">
              <div>Password</div>
              <div className="form-input-input">
                <input
                  type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                  value={loginPassword ? loginPassword : ""}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setLoginPassword(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  className="form-input-title"
                />
                <span className="p-viewer" onClick={togglePasswordVisibility}>
                  {showPassword ? <FaEyeSlash /> : <FaEye />}
                </span>
              </div>
           </div>
```

```css
.form-input {
  text-align: left;
}

.form-input > div:first-child {
  color: #aaa; /* Set the font color to #aaa */
}

.form-input input {
  border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170) !important;
  background: transparent;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 14px
}
.form-input-title {
  text-align: left;
}

.p-viewer {
  
 position: relative;
  right: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: grey;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: The .p-viewer class (child element) should have the position absolute, while the .form-input-input class (parent element) should have position relative. And then play around with top, left and padding (padding on the input element, so the input text/placeholder doesn't fall behind the icon) until it looks the way you want it to!